# What command should I use to explicitly set list of groups and execute a command?

Tags: group, su

To execute a command as other uid, one uses `su`. The list of supplementary groups is not specified on command line, but instead read from configuration files (`/etc/passwd`, `/etc/group`), etc.

Which tool shall I use to change into arbitrary uid with arbitrary supplementary groups? The tool should not read any files, just do `setuid/setgid/setgroups` and `execve` my command.

I expect something like this:

```
# su_ll 10137 --groups 10137,4002,4006,4010 /usr/bin/id
uid=10137 gid=10137 groups=10137,4002,4006,4010
```

Use case: starting shell with application's privileges in Android. Simple `su` or `run-as` is not enough, as it does not fill in necessary groups, resulting in missing network access when the application does have network access.

Comment: Implemented this mode in my tool: https://github.com/vi/dive/blob/d9eb80d52d29614eda935f4a2eab0a2d8aad08de/dived.1#L197

Comment: With `sudo`, you can assign the primary group (`-g`) and user (`-u`), and leave the groups otherwise unaffected (`-P`) so that your groups are applied to the program... which then changes the problem to setting your group list. :/